# Conditional column applying to a subset of rows in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have the following table:

```
row_number itemID   score
1           45      99
2           45      47
1           46      98
2           46      20
1           47      98
2           47      20
…           …        …
```

Which is the output of the following query:

```
SET @num := 0, @itemID_grouping := ''; 

SELECT row_number, 
       itemID, 
       score 
FROM   (SELECT itemID, 
               score, 
               @num := IF(@itemID_grouping = itemID, @num + 1, 1) AS row_number, 
               @itemID_grouping := itemID                         AS temp 
        FROM   my_table 
        ORDER  BY itemID, 
                  score DESC) AS x 
WHERE  x.row_number <= 2;
```

From the following original table:

```
my_table: 
itemID score
 46     99
 …      …
```

So for each `itemID`, I have a set of two values (the two highest scores).

I'd like another column that contains 'y' or 1 if, for each set, the number with `row_number=1` is greater than a certain threshold and the number with `row_number=2` is lower than a certain threshold. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

OK I found an answer (it might not be very fast but it does the job):

```
set @num := 0, @itemID_grouping := '',@num_temp:=0,@flag1:=0,@flag2:=0;

select row_number,itemID, score,flag2
from 
(
   select itemID,score,
      @num := if(@itemID_grouping = itemID, @num + 1, 1) as row_number,
      @flag1:= if(@num=1 AND score>90,1,0) as flag1,
      @flag2:= if(@num=2 AND @flag_temp=1 AND score<70,1,0) as flag2, 
      @itemID_grouping := itemID as temp,
      @flag_temp:=@flag1 as temp_flag
  from my_table
  order by itemID,score desc
) as x 
where x.row_number <= 2;
```